# Cant get animation to behave the same with two different gestures - react native reanimated + gesture handler

Tags: react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm having trouble with a very simple animation. When I press and drag a handle to the bottom of the screen, I expect a small container at the top to fade opacity to 0 and height to 0 and also expanding the wrapping container height at the same time, revealing another view below the top container using the pan gesture handler event. Everything should work in reverse.

The other scenario is when I press and fling the handle it should do the same in either direction (UP | DOWN)

The problem I'm facing is that dragging the control up and down works as I expect it and I'm almost happy with how it works but flinging the handle does not give the same results. The main container changes it's size but the small container does not animate its height and opacity like when panning.

Also, this works fine on iOS but not working at all on Android.

[Here is a snack to illustrate the issue](https://snack.expo.dev/@francot/gesture-handler-)

Comment: I managed to fix the issue where it is not working on Android. I did not wrap my app with `GestureHandlerRootView`